# Why do Doctypes prevent Javascript from working?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, doctype

With the help of some good people here on Stack Overflow, I was able to fix a Javascript on a simple text html page. Here is the final code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="imageid" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="images/bracelet-1.jpg" alt="image" width="200" > 
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var img = document.getElementById('imageid');
     var normsizeimg = img.style.width;
     var bigwidth = 600;

     function bigImg(x)
     { x.style.width = bigwidth; }
     function normalImg(x) { x.style.width = normsizeimg; }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hover your mouse over the image, and it enlarges. Simple.

However, if we add ANY Doctype statement at the top of the code, the script stops working. It doesn't matter whether it's an HTML4 Doctype, an HTML5 Doctype, or one of the XHTML Doctype flavors. Can someone please tell me why this happens and what can be done about it?

This is important because I want to be able to center a table-less page using `margin: 0 auto`, and that only works when you have a Doctype.

Comment: What browser? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Stops working entirely? I'm sensing a quirksmode vs. standards mode error here.

Comment: DOCTYPE affects the box model

Comment: @tkone: This happens with IE, FF, Chrome, and Safari

Answer (score 4):

It turns out, in Standards mode, you cannot provide numbers to `x.style.width`. You have to provide a string ending with `'px'` instead.

This works:

```
function bigImg ( x ) {
  x.style.width = bigwidth + 'px';
}

function normalImg ( x ) { 
  x.style.width = normsizeimg + 'px';
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/e3d2P/

---

Alternatively, this also works:

```
function bigImg ( x ) {
  x.width = bigwidth;
}

function normalImg ( x ) { 
  x.width = normsizeimg;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/e3d2P/1/

---

However, as @Jan's answer shows, increasing the size of images on hover can be done with CSS alone.

Comment: Yup, this is the proper solution. Knew it had to do with standards mode vs. quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use javascript for this, use CSS! It's more semantic, more readable and performs a lot better.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #imageid { width:200px }
      #imageid:hover { width:600px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="imageid" src="images/bracelet-1.jpg" alt="image"> 
  </body>
</html>
```